# Перегрузка оператора [] для вложенных классов

Tags: c++

Пример: пусть у нас имеется класс `TMatrix`, в инстанцированный объект которого инкапсулированн двумерный массив элементов типа `int`. Возможное решение для получения его конкретного элемента - функция `getEntrie(int row, int col)` возвращающая элемент по номеру строки и столбца.

Другое решение - создание вложенного класса, например `TPtrRow`, который хранит в себе указатель на `int`. Тогда, мы перегружаем оператор [] для класса TMatrix так, чтобы он возвращал объект TPtrRow, хранящий в себе строку, номер которой мы передали при вызове []. Аналогично, перегружаем оператор[] для класса `TPtrRow` - тогда употребив два оператор подряд `obj[row][col]` мы получим нужный нам элемент.

Собственно, вопрос: каким образом подобную конструкцию можно имплементировать к тем случаям, когда мы имеем дело с N-мерными массивами, N > 2 ?

Comment: Обобщите `TPtrRow`, чтобы каждый последовательный вызов возвращал класс матрицы с размерностью на единицу меньше исходной.

Comment: @Arhad, Вы имеете ввиду, сделать класс `TPtrRow` шаблонным ?

Comment: Можно и так, причём параметризовать шаблон размерностью возвращаемой подматрицы. Для одномерной же матрицы определить шаблонную специализацию, возвращающую итоговое значение ячейки вместо очередной матрицы.

Comment: @Arhad, судя по Вашему "можно и так..", Вы хотели предложить что-то другое ?)

Comment: Можно вместо цепочки из операторов `[]` использовать оператор `()`, принимающий сразу все измерения.

Comment: Нет, не "можно", дорогой друг )) Хотелось бы узнать реализацию именно такого способа.

Comment: @isnullxbh: Вот именно таким способом и имплементировать. Подход естественным образом работает для любого `N`. Почему возник вопрос? Или у вас `N` не является константой времени компиляции? Если это так, то это надо указывать в вопросе явно, ибо в этом вся его суть.

Comment: Допустим так, на этапе компиляции мы не знаем, каким может быть N. Можете объянсить, что это меняет ?

Comment: @isnullxbh: Если `N` - константа времени компиляции, то подобная вложенная структура для любого `N` реализуется очевидным образом (вами же и описанным). Это можно сделать явно "в лоб", а можно и элегантно методами шаблонного программирования. Но как только `N` становится величиной времени выполнения, это меняет все радикальнейшим образом. Это будет вообще совсем другая задача. В этом случае о реализации было бы говорить рано. Сначала надо было бы решить вопросы дизайна.

Comment: Вы умеете заинтриговать. Может есть линки на какие-то интересные статьи ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну можно немного поколдовать с variadic templates, если в вашем распоряжении есть С++11:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T, int size>
class Row{
public:
    typedef T ValueType;
private:
    ValueType _items[size];
public:

    ValueType& operator[](int index){
        return _items[index];
    }
};

template<class T, int ...sizes>
struct Table{
    template<class TR, int sizeR, int ...sizesR>
    struct Rebind{
        typedef Row<typename Rebind<TR, sizesR...>::Type, sizeR> Type;
        typedef Row<typename Rebind<TR, sizeR, sizesR...>::Type, sizeR> ValueType;
    };
    template<class TR, int sizeR>
    struct Rebind<TR, sizeR>{
        typedef Row<TR, sizeR> Type;
        typedef typename Type::ValueType ValueType;
    };
    typedef typename Rebind<T, sizes...>::Type Items;
public:
    typedef typename Items::ValueType ValueType;
private:
    Items _items;
public:
    ValueType& operator[](int index){
        return _items[index];
    }

};

int main(){
    Table<int, 5, 2, 4, 5, 9> table;
    table[3][1][3][3][7] = 42;
    std::cout << table[3][1][3][3][7];
}
```

Думаю этот код можно как-то упростить используя `using` из С++11, но я, если честно, им ни разу не пользовался :)

**PS:** Как по мне проще затайпдефить несколько вложенных строк

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T, int size>
class Row{
public:
    typedef T ValueType;
private:
    ValueType _items[size];
public:

    ValueType& operator[](int index){
        return _items[index];
    }
};

template<class T>
using Table = Row<Row<Row<Row<Row<T, 9>, 5>, 4>, 2>, 5>;

int main(){
    Table<int> table;

    table[3][1][3][3][7] = 42;
    std::cout << table[3][1][3][3][7];
}
```