# Шаблонный класс, реализующий многомерный массив

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Пока не совсем дружу с шаблонами, прошу пример реализации многомерного массива на основе шаблонов. Чтобы использовался примерно так:

```
// ...
Matrix<int> M1(10); // массив с одним измерением
Matrix<std::string> M2(2,3,4); // массив с тремя измерениями
Matrix<double,2,3,4> M3; // и такой вариант вызова устроит
// ...
M2.At(1,1,0) = "элемент массива";
// ...
```

**Что дополнительно нужно:**

- нужна только реализация конструктора и метода At, возвращающего ссылку на нужный элемент многомерного массива
- если в конструкторе вообще аргументов нет - нужен вызов static_assert
- ecли в методе At количество аргументов не соответствует количеству аргументов конструктора - нужен вызов static_assert
- ecли в методе At аргументы выходят за диапазон - нужен проброс std::range_error
- содержимое многомерного массива строить на основе std::vector<T>

Весьма буду признателен за мастер-класс! :-)

**Мой "сырой" вариант, в процессе доработки ...**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, std::size_t ...Dims>
class Matrix {
  public:
    Matrix() {
     // собираем "измерения"
     DimVars = {Dims...};
     // резервируем "ячейки" в одномерном массиве
     BuffLen = std::accumulate(DimVars.begin(), DimVars.end(), 1, std::multiplies<std::size_t>());
     Buff.resize(BuffLen);
    }
    void Print() {
      for(const auto &i:DimVars) std::cout << i << ":";
      std::cout << "\n";
    }
  private:
    std::vector<std::size_t> DimVars;
    std::vector<T> Buff;
    std::size_t BuffLen;
};

int main() {
  try {
    Matrix<int,1,2,3> M1;
    M1.Print();
    Matrix<int,1,2,3,4,5,6> M2;
    M2.Print();
  } catch(...) {
    std::cout << "Error\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: Работа в переменным числом параметров. Если параметр один - его значение берется с потолка. И вообще я не уверен, что использование va_list - это с++ way. И второй момент - static_assert требует константного выражения, а с подстановкой через va_list я этого не получаю. Возможно можно как-то использовать тут вариардики, но фантазии (и знаний) не хватает.

Comment: @Majestio, `static_assert` работает с выражениями вычисленными на этапе компиляции. А количество аргументов в `va_list` можно определить только на этапе выполнения, так что эти вещи друг с другом не совместимы по определению. Вам нужно использовать variadic templates

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, да, я понимаю. В вопросе добавил третий вариант вызова - в принципе тоже пойдет.

Comment: @Majestio, я отвечал на отдаленно похожий вопрос. Посмотрите, может он чем-нибудь вам поможет http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/558264/191211

Comment: Спасибо, поразбираюсь!

Comment: @Majestio, отличия следующие. Вместо `at` `operator[]`. В случае неправильного набора параметров возникает ошибка компиляции, вместо `static_assert`. То же касается `at`, если вызывать неверное количество операторов, то возвращаемое значение будет типа `Row<int, 1, 2 /*...*/>`, а не `int`, что тоже даст ошибку компиляции. Выход за границы в лучших традициях C++ не проверяется. Так как размеры таблицы известны заранее, используется обычный массив.

Comment: На всякий случай - `Matrix<double,2,3,4> M3();` - это не вызов, а объявление функции `M3` :)

Comment: Да нет, у меня конструктор вызывается.

Comment: @Majestio, думаю Harry говорит о [most vexing parse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). http://ideone.com/uoZNM1

Comment: Все возможно. Но не в моем случае, я проверял - идет вызов конструктора.

Answer (score 6):

Пришёл к такому варианту:

```
template<typename... Values>
using AreCorrectIndicies_t = std::tuple<std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Values>::value>...>;

template <typename T, size_t... Dimensions>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix()
    {
        std::array<size_t, sizeof...(Dimensions)> dimensions{Dimensions...};
        size_t size = std::accumulate(dimensions.begin(), dimensions.end(), size_t{1}, std::multiplies<>{});
        m_Container.resize(size);
    }

    template<typename... Values, typename = AreCorrectIndicies_t<Values...>>
    T& At(Values... indicies)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(indicies) == sizeof...(Dimensions), "Dimensions don't match!");
        std::array<size_t, sizeof...(indicies)> input{static_cast<size_t>(indicies)...};
        std::array<size_t, sizeof...(indicies)> dimensions{Dimensions...};
        for(size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(input[i] >= dimensions[i])
                throw std::runtime_error{"Wrong indicies"};
        }
        return _getElement(input);
    }
private:
    T& _getElement(const std::array<size_t, sizeof...(Dimensions)>& indicies)
    {
        return m_Container[_calculateIndex(indicies)];
    }

    size_t _calculateIndex(const std::array<size_t, sizeof...(Dimensions)>& indicies)
    {
        std::array<size_t, sizeof...(Dimensions)> dimensions{Dimensions...};
        size_t internalIndex = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < indicies.size(); ++i)
        {
            auto span = std::accumulate(dimensions.begin() + i + 1, dimensions.end(), indicies[i],
                std::multiplies<>{}); 
            internalIndex += span;
        }
        return internalIndex;
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> m_Container;
};
```

Идея проста: плоский массив, в котором индекс высчитывается при обращении. Многое в этом коде можно доработать, оптимизировать и улучшить. К примеру, `std::vector` тут вообще не нужен, его можно заменить на `std::array` и т.п.

Пример использования на [ideone](http://ideone.com/4ItHRe).

Comment: Пасип! Для мастер-класса самое то!)) У меня тож наклевывается вариант, немного похожий, но пока вроде проще. Сделаю - опубликую. А насчет std::array вместо std::vector - сомнительно, в планах реализация изменения размерностей и их количества в рантайме.

Comment: Хотя ... если будет меняться количество размерностей в рантайме, то о static_assert в методе At можно забыть ... Надо подумать что важнее ...